# SARIMAX ValueError: xnames and params do not have the same length

Tags: statistics, statsmodels, arima

I am running SARIMAX and I am getting the following error:

ValueError: xnames and params do not have the same length.

I need help understanding what this error means and how I can avoid it.

This is the model that I am trying to run using statsmodels in python:

mod = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(y,order=(1, 1, 1), seasonal_order=(1, 1, 1, 12), enforce_stationarity=False, enforce_invertibility=False)